# Displaying Database in Gridview

Tags: c#, html, css, webforms

When setting Datasource for gridview everything works fine and it shows my table perfectly and connects fine. Once I'm done setting up datasource and go into design view it shows my column titles correctly but the data from my query is no longer there.

Finally, Once I debug in browser the page is completely blank. No gridview, no table, just a blank page. I would like to know what code I need for this to show up on the webpage as well as make sure any sample data I queried shows up.

Every tutorial I watch they do the exact same thing that I did except when they view in browser the table and data is actually there. I did notice It changed my query up quite a bit after I wrote the query in DataSource.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Assetmvc.Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" DataKeyNames="EmployeeId,id,ItemId,Expr3,ModelID,CompSerial,PhoneSerial,TabletSerial,PrinterSerial,DockSerial,BoosterSerial,SleeveSerial,GloveSerial" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeId" HeaderText="EmployeeId" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="EmployeeId" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="HiredDate" HeaderText="HiredDate" SortExpression="HiredDate" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FiredDate" HeaderText="FiredDate" SortExpression="FiredDate" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CurrentItems" HeaderText="CurrentItems" SortExpression="CurrentItems" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SupervisorId" HeaderText="SupervisorId" SortExpression="SupervisorId" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SupervisorName" HeaderText="SupervisorName" SortExpression="SupervisorName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr1" HeaderText="Expr1" SortExpression="Expr1" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr2" HeaderText="Expr2" SortExpression="Expr2" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="JobID" HeaderText="JobID" SortExpression="JobID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="State" HeaderText="State" SortExpression="State" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemId" HeaderText="ItemId" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ItemId" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemType" HeaderText="ItemType" SortExpression="ItemType" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DateAssigned" HeaderText="DateAssigned" SortExpression="DateAssigned" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ManifactureId" HeaderText="ManifactureId" SortExpression="ManifactureId" />
                    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Disposed" HeaderText="Disposed" SortExpression="Disposed" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ReturnDate" HeaderText="ReturnDate" SortExpression="ReturnDate" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr3" HeaderText="Expr3" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Expr3" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ManifactureName" HeaderText="ManifactureName" SortExpression="ManifactureName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ModelName" HeaderText="ModelName" SortExpression="ModelName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ModelID" HeaderText="ModelID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ModelID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr4" HeaderText="Expr4" SortExpression="Expr4" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CompSerial" HeaderText="CompSerial" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CompSerial" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ManifacturerID" HeaderText="ManifacturerID" SortExpression="ManifacturerID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Model" HeaderText="Model" SortExpression="Model" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OperatingSystem" HeaderText="OperatingSystem" SortExpression="OperatingSystem" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="WarrantyEnd" HeaderText="WarrantyEnd" SortExpression="WarrantyEnd" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="HDSize" HeaderText="HDSize" SortExpression="HDSize" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PhoneSerial" HeaderText="PhoneSerial" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PhoneSerial" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ServiceProvider" HeaderText="ServiceProvider" SortExpression="ServiceProvider" />
                    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="TelogisOnly" HeaderText="TelogisOnly" SortExpression="TelogisOnly" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr5" HeaderText="Expr5" SortExpression="Expr5" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PhoneNum" HeaderText="PhoneNum" SortExpression="PhoneNum" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr6" HeaderText="Expr6" SortExpression="Expr6" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TabletSerial" HeaderText="TabletSerial" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TabletSerial" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr7" HeaderText="Expr7" SortExpression="Expr7" />
                    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Expr8" HeaderText="Expr8" SortExpression="Expr8" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr9" HeaderText="Expr9" SortExpression="Expr9" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr10" HeaderText="Expr10" SortExpression="Expr10" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PrinterSerial" HeaderText="PrinterSerial" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PrinterSerial" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr11" HeaderText="Expr11" SortExpression="Expr11" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr12" HeaderText="Expr12" SortExpression="Expr12" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DockSerial" HeaderText="DockSerial" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DockSerial" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr13" HeaderText="Expr13" SortExpression="Expr13" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr14" HeaderText="Expr14" SortExpression="Expr14" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="BoosterSerial" HeaderText="BoosterSerial" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="BoosterSerial" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr15" HeaderText="Expr15" SortExpression="Expr15" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr16" HeaderText="Expr16" SortExpression="Expr16" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SleeveSerial" HeaderText="SleeveSerial" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="SleeveSerial" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="IssueDate" HeaderText="IssueDate" SortExpression="IssueDate" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ExpireDate" HeaderText="ExpireDate" SortExpression="ExpireDate" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SleeveStatus" HeaderText="SleeveStatus" SortExpression="SleeveStatus" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="GloveSerial" HeaderText="GloveSerial" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="GloveSerial" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="GloveStatus" HeaderText="GloveStatus" SortExpression="GloveStatus" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Size" HeaderText="Size" SortExpression="Size" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr17" HeaderText="Expr17" SortExpression="Expr17" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr18" HeaderText="Expr18" SortExpression="Expr18" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Note" HeaderText="Note" SortExpression="Note" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr19" HeaderText="Expr19" SortExpression="Expr19" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr20" HeaderText="Expr20" SortExpression="Expr20" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AssetTrackingConnectionString3 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Employees.EmployeeId, Employees.FirstName, Employees.LastName, Employees.HiredDate, Employees.FiredDate, Employees.CurrentItems, Employees.SupervisorId, Employees.SupervisorName, Job.id, Job.SupervisorID AS Expr1, Job.SupervisorName AS Expr2, Job.JobID, Job.City, Job.State, Items.ItemId, Items.ItemType, Items.DateAssigned, Items.ManifactureId, Items.Disposed, Items.ReturnDate, Manifacturer.ManifactureID AS Expr3, Manifacturer.ManifactureName, Models.ModelName, Models.ModelID, Models.ManifactureID AS Expr4, Computers.CompSerial, Computers.ManifacturerID, Computers.Model, Computers.OperatingSystem, Computers.WarrantyEnd, Computers.HDSize, Phones.PhoneSerial, Phones.ServiceProvider, Phones.TelogisOnly, Phones.ModelId AS Expr5, Phones.PhoneNum, Phones.ManifactureID AS Expr6, Tablets.TabletSerial, Tablets.ServiceProvider AS Expr7, Tablets.TelogisOnly AS Expr8, Tablets.ModelId AS Expr9, Tablets.Phonenum AS Expr10, Printers.PrinterSerial, Printers.ManifactureID AS Expr11, Printers.Model AS Expr12, Docks.DockSerial, Docks.WarrantyEnd AS Expr13, Docks.ManifactureID AS Expr14, CellBoosters.BoosterSerial, CellBoosters.ManifacturerID AS Expr15, CellBoosters.Model AS Expr16, Sleeves.SleeveSerial, Sleeves.IssueDate, Sleeves.ExpireDate, Sleeves.SleeveStatus, Gloves.GloveSerial, Gloves.GloveStatus, Gloves.Size, Gloves.IssueDate AS Expr17, Gloves.ExpireDate AS Expr18, Notes.Note, Notes.EmployeeID AS Expr19, Notes.ItemId AS Expr20, Notes.Date FROM Employees CROSS JOIN Job CROSS JOIN Items CROSS JOIN Manifacturer CROSS JOIN Models CROSS JOIN Computers CROSS JOIN Phones CROSS JOIN Tablets CROSS JOIN Printers CROSS JOIN Docks CROSS JOIN CellBoosters CROSS JOIN Sleeves CROSS JOIN Gloves CROSS JOIN Notes"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </div>

            </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have some pretty significant issues just in your sql. You are using the antiquated AMSI-89 style join. You should use the "modern" ANSI-92 style join. They have been around more than 30 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins But do you really have separate tables for tablets, computers, etc??? And don't use select *, select ONLY the columns you actually need. If it isn't too late I might also suggest that there is no "i" in Manufacturer.

Comment: Honestly I'm just trying to get data to show up right now and once I make that happen I'll go back and edit the SQL properly. I don't think that would cause the data to not show up would it?  Also, Why would I not have separate tables for each item? If I need to sort my data by item then yes I am going to separate each into different tables. I'm new to sql but I think the issue here relates to some C# or html I'm missing more so than spelling or bad SQL. Like I stated the tables show up fine in design mode just not in the browser.

Comment: You should have a products table with a column for type. If you use a different table for each type of product you have to constantly keep updating your queries to accommodate new products. That defeats the purpose. You can sort items based on type without being in different tables. Honestly for me the design of your database is far more of an issue than your page not showing anything. That design is going to make you want to jump on a sword.

Comment: Does that query run? Do you get back the same column names as defined in your table? ManifacturerID1, ManifacturerID6 etc??? Something is really way wrong here but without knowledge of your current tables it is impossible to know what that might be.

Comment: Yeah the query ran fine. I noticed it added numbers on each of the manufacturers which I'll have to fix. It's Literally the first time I've ever made anything in SQL so I'm sure it sucks pretty bad. The reason I put each item in seperate tables is because each employee is assigned 1 of each item and I need Serial, model, ext for each type of item next to each employees name. The way I was thinking was if I had one table with a column for type I would only be able to put one product for each employee and they all have multiple items with data for each item.

Comment: Also for the most part unless fired or broken the data for each item the employees have won't really change and no new items will be added. I'll be making the tables editable via the website just for the few occurances that an employee does leave or switch phone models, comp models, ext.

Comment: @Sean Lange I think your right. It has to be something to do with the query. VS edited my query in the datasource window for some reason and I didn't notice. Added a bunch of cross joins. When I changed the datasource to just one table instead of all of them it worked fine. Based on my description above for what I need what do you think would be the best way to organize my tables?

Comment: I couldn't begin to suggest how to structure your tables from what is posted here.

Comment: What would you like to see? I could screen shot something if that'd help.